# jQuery - now: Creating an object and storing values in it to pass to an AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have an array:

```
myarr = [];
```

I'm filling it with some values:

```
myarray['name'] = "Me!";
```

Now I want to transform that array into a set of Key => Value pairs. I though jQuery would do it automatically, but it doesn't seem to.

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "myurl",
    data: myarr
});
```

Is there a way to do this or something I'm doing wrong? I get no  javascript errors, and no serverside errors other then no POST information at all.

I need the request to be sent as a **true POST request**. I need to keep the php code simple because sometimes the login *won't* be an AJAX call.

I'm now trying the following with an error `unexepected token ':'`

```
myarr:
{
    'name':'me'
}
```

The question has now become: **How do I initialize a new javascript object as "blank", how do I set up mappings, and how do I pass it in an AJAX call?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data attribute is an object, so it uses notation like so:

```
data: { 'Name': 'Me!' }
```

Not

```
data: ['Name':'Me!']
```

You need to convert your array to an object. You can easily do this in place of an array:

```
myData.Name = 'Me';
myData.OtherProp = 'Something';
```

Here's some samples:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text/html',
    url: 'myUrl.php',
    data:
    {
        'Name': 'Me!'
    },
    success: function(data, status)
    {
        // data is the returned response
    }
});
```

OR

```
var myObject = new Object();

myObject.Name = 'Me!';

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'text/html',
    url: 'myUrl.php',
    data: myObject
});
```

Both should get you to the right place.

Comment: But I've sent strings like `name=me&user=new&date=today` in the data field before with no problems. I need to know how it's coming out on the server side. It needs to be a true POST request.

Comment: jQuery does the transformation from an object to posted data for you.

Comment: Awesome, let me try that. I figured it would transform that array, but I guess not.

Comment: Can you clarify a little more on the syntax please?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass the array directly, you need to encode it first and then pass it. For example you can use json2.js from [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html) to encode it as JSON:

```
var mydata = JSON.stringify(myarr);
$.ajax
({
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "text",
 url: "myurl",
 data: {"mydata" : mydata}
});
```

Then you will need to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in PHP to convert the JSON string back to an array.

**Update**

To address your new questions:

**How do I initialize a new javascript object as "blank"?**

You can create a new object like so:

```
var myObj = {};
```

**How do I set up mappings?**

There are a couple different ways:

```
myObj.name = "Me!";
myObj['name'] = "Me!";
```

**How do I pass it in an AJAX call?**

Just pass it directly as the `data` argument:

```
data: myObj
```

Comment: I like it, but right now I'm using CodeIgniter and I can't put a `json_decode` call in there. I need to just send it as a true set of POST values.

Comment: I am using CodeIgniter also, and have used `json_decode` in my app from time to time. For example: `$data = json_decode($this->input->post('mydata'), true);`

Comment: I'll give it a look, though can you clarify any of the syntax Tejs gave?

Comment: @Josh - I just updated my answer to directly respond to your new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Continue exactly like you have been, but change [ to { and ] to } (which changes your array to an object)